# Replace ID column in LTREE with different column Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a hierarchical structure in postgres which uses LTREE to calculate path based on a trigger. I am following the examples  from here: https://coderwall.com/p/whf3-a/hierarchical-data-in-postgres

Table, trigger and data being inserted look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE section (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
asset_name TEXT,
parent_id INTEGER REFERENCES section,
parent_path LTREE
);

CREATE INDEX section_parent_path_idx ON section USING GIST (parent_path);
CREATE INDEX section_parent_id_idx ON section (parent_id);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_section_parent_path() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    path ltree;
BEGIN
    IF NEW.parent_id IS NULL THEN
        NEW.parent_path = '6'::ltree;
    ELSEIF TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR OLD.parent_id IS NULL OR OLD.parent_id != NEW.parent_id THEN
        SELECT parent_path || id::text FROM section WHERE id = NEW.parent_id INTO path;
        IF path IS NULL THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid parent_id %', NEW.parent_id;
        END IF;
        NEW.parent_path = path;
    END IF;

        ltree_array = (STRING_TO_ARRAY(path::TEXT,'.'))[2:2147483647]; 

        IF ltree_array IS NOT NULL THEN 
            FOREACH entry IN ARRAY(ltree_array)
            LOOP
                v_asset_name  = (SELECT asset_name
                                 FROM section AS s
                                 WHERE s.id = entry);

                s3path = s3path || v_asset_name || '/';
            END LOOP;
        END IF;


        s3path = NEW.asset_store_id || '/' || s3path || NEW.asset_name;
        NEW.s3_path = s3path;


    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER parent_path_tgr
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON section
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_section_parent_path();

INSERT INTO section (id, asset_name, parent_id ) VALUES (1, 'Main Folder', NULL);
INSERT INTO section (id, asset_name, parent_id ) VALUES (2, 'Rejected', 1);
INSERT INTO section (id, asset_name, parent_id ) VALUES (3, 'Records', NULL);
INSERT INTO section (id, asset_name, parent_id ) VALUES (4, 'Expired', 3);
INSERT INTO section (id, asset_name, parent_id ) VALUES (5, 'Selected', 3);
INSERT INTO section (id, asset_name, parent_id ) VALUES (6, 'Useless', 5);
```

The table output looks like this:

```
id|asset_name |parent_id|parent_path|
--|-----------|---------|-----------|
 1|Main Folder|         |6          |
 2|Rejected   |        1|6.1        |
 3|Records    |         |6          |
 4|Expired    |        3|6.3        |
 5|Selected   |        3|6.3        |
 6|Useless    |        5|6.3.5      |
```

`parent_path` is all numerical because it looks like it is concatinating `id`, but I want to concatinate `asset_name` column.

I have tried replacing `id` with `asset_name` but that throws an syntax error. I can't seem to figure out how to replace id within the trigger.

Comment: Personally I found it easier to work with `int_array`s instead of `ltree`.

Comment: So your current solution is working, you only want to use names instead of ids?

Comment: What exactly is the syntax error you're getting? Please [edit] your question to include the code you tried and the error message. (My guess is that your `asset_name`s don't follow the `ltree` syntax requirements, you'd need to remove the blank / replace it by underscore, and maybe lowercase the string)

Comment: @Bergi I think you are right about the `asset_name` not conforming to ltree syntax. I was playing around with the trigger so can't reproduce the exaxct error message. My solution was to  add another column that would take the ltree path and parse out the asset name and create the full path needed.  I can't change the `asset_name` itself as that has to match what is in S3 bucket.